# Writing an accent and evolving

Tags: fiction, language, accent

Sometimes I read written accents in books, most notably maybe Hagrid in Harry Potter. I find it a fun way to add a layer to a character that sets them apart from the rest.

Could you "evolve" it by slowly removing the accent throughout the story? Or would it pull you out of the book if every so often a word you spelled one way before, changed now.

Say, character A is new to Scotland and barely understands Scottish. But then he resides there for years and every passing month keeps understanding it better and better.
So where he would hear "I cannae", he now hears it as "I cannot".

Very curious to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like to read books written (partly) in an accent or dialect. The reason for this is twofold. For one, the written variants of most accents and dialects aren't properly formalized. Everyone who writes, say, a German speaking English will spell that German accent differently so that as a reader you can never really know how you are supposed to pronounce what you read. And, while I have, through decades of reading and writing, a high fluency in the standard written language, I have absolutely no familiarity with the majority of accents and dialects that writers write, so that reading them feels rather like an obstruction to my understanding than an enrichment of my reading experience.

If you *must* have some character in your story encounter or speak with an accent or dialect, I therefore much prefer if that accent or dialect is briefly shown when the character is introduced and then **quickly faded out**.

Think about how charaters in books speak or encounter foreign languages. There may be a few sentences or some phrases in that language, but then (when, presumably, the character has learned the language) we are given the translation of what they say and hear.

A good example is the novel *Shogun*, where the protagonist learns Japanese at the beginning of the book (where we read some Japanese words and phrases) and as soon as he masters the language the Japanese dialogue is given in perfect English.

I would do the same for a dialect or accent that a character sheds over the course of the book.

I, personally, would never write a character that has an accent that stays unchanged for the whole story. I don't like to read that, so I don't force it on my readers, either. The only exception would be if language was the main topic of the book. But just as part of the characterization it seems too much of an irritant to me.

Comment: It used to be considered acceptable to write dialogue in a 'phonetic' transcription of the character's accent , like Kipling's Irish soldier [Terence Mulvaney](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-courting-of-dinah-shadd.htm), but most modern readers, like Ben, just find it irritating and difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think you described an effective solution to something in your story that could reasonably present a barrier to your readers.  My personal opinions on the use of a patois or the vernacular of your dialogue are immaterial. Filtering the dialogue through your viewpoint character's interpretation feels like an effective approach.

I think though since you are deliberately kind of annoying your reader -- and possibly entertaining them -- that some plot element of the story needs to be dependent on this challenge facing the character.  For instance, if the only problem this language barrier presents the character is they can't order a decent breakfast or keep getting a shite beer in the pub rather than ordering something they want, then I wonder if the aggravation to the reader is worth it.

If you are using this problem to show case the character's personal traits -- they are easily frustrated or they have tremendous patients ... whatever -- and running them through situations were this communication problem is really a problem that supports to arc of the story, then I'd think that you are on to a good plan.

If its just there, like it serves no real purpose and then goes away, then I don't think it will end up being a benefit to your story.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great insight. I think you are hitting some great points here and will definitely keep them in mind!